# How can I render only the attributes of my model in returned JSON?

Tags: python, json, django, python-3.x, view

I'm using Python 3.7 and Django.  I have a view that returns the following

```
# Ajax request that returns articles with similar words in the titles
def get_hints(request):
    ...
    s = ArticlesService()
    objects = s.get_hints(article)
    data = serializers.serialize('json', objects)
    return HttpResponse(data, content_type="application/json")
```

The "get_hints" method returns an array of model objects.  The thing is, on the Javascript side, the JSON is returned like so ...

```
[{model: "mydb.article", pk: 60945, fields: { title: "Cooking Eggplant", path: "https://thecookingblog.com/abcde", label: "" },
    ...]
```

Is there a way to have the JSON returned without the "model" and "fields" and just have the object's attribute returned as more traditional JSON, e.g.

```
{ title: "Cooking Eggplant", path: "https://thecookingblog.com/abcde", label: "" }
```

?

Comment: Yes, use another serializer, the Django provided one is intended for exporting and loading data in the database. The django-rest-framework has the serializer you want.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [django: control json serialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129794/django-control-json-serialization)

Comment: @dirkgroten, In the answer you listed, they are building the JSON from scratch, one attribute at a time. If that's the only way to do it, so be it, but I was hoping there was something I coudl pass an object into taht woudl do all the hard work for me.

Comment: Then refer to my first comment. User the ModelSerializer from DRF.

Comment: that something is called a serializer. Either find a Django package that has serialisers that are easy to configure and flexible (DRF has that) or write your own serializer class. The answer of Abdul below is a good start to build a simple serializer that'll serialise all your model's fields.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The [`get_dump_object`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/b9cf764be62e77b4777b3a75ec256f6209a57671/django/core/serializers/python.py#L35) method of the [`Serializer`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/b9cf764be62e77b4777b3a75ec256f6209a57671/django/core/serializers/python.py#L14) class is responsible for the below format

```
{
    "pk": "pk_val",
    "model": "model_name",
    "fields": {
        "model_field": "model_field_value",
        ...
    }
}
```

Following is the current implementation of the `get_dump_object` method.

```
def get_dump_object(self, obj):
    data = OrderedDict([('model', str(obj._meta))])
    if not self.use_natural_primary_keys or not hasattr(obj, 'natural_key'):
        data["pk"] = self._value_from_field(obj, obj._meta.pk)
    data['fields'] = self._current
    return data
```

Since you don't want the `pk` and `model` fields you can create  your own serialzer class and override `get_dump_object` method.

```
from django.core.serializers.json import Serializer as JSONSerializer

class MyCustomSerializer(JSONSerializer):
    def get_dump_object(self, obj):
        return self._current
```

and then you can get the data in the following format

```
[{ title: "Cooking Eggplant", path: "https://thecookingblog.com/abcde", label: "" }, ....]
```

by calling its `serialize` method.

```
data = MyCustomSerializer().serialize(objects)
return HttpResponse(data, content_type="application/json")
```

Comment: I don't mind having the pk, its just I'd like the object to be represented as a single JSON entity as opposed to the way it is now.  Do I still need to write a custom function to dump that data?

Comment: If you want "pk" then instead of returning `self._current` you can do `data = super().get_dump_object(obj); return {'pk': data['pk'], **data['fields']}`

Comment: Where am I writing that?  In the custom function you have?